# Severity: error --> Exception: "$email" must be an instance of SendGrid\Mail\From or a valid email address

Tags: php, email, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

Here is my code and issue Severity: error --> Exception: "$email" must be an instance of SendGrid\Mail\From or a valid email address

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
        $email = new \SendGrid\Mail\Mail();
        $email->setFrom($this->ecomhut->getConfig('salesEmail'));
        $email->setSubject($subject);
        
        $email->addTo($data['email']);
        
        //$email->addBcc($this->ecomhut->getConfig('supportEmail'));
        
        $email->addBcc($this->ecomhut->getConfig('ForwarderEmail'));
        
        $email->setReplyTo($this->ecomhut->getConfig('supportEmail'),NULL);
        
        $email->addContent(
            "text/html", $template
        );
        
        $sendgrid = new \SendGrid($this->SENDGRID_API_KEY);
        
        try {
            $response = $sendgrid->send($email);
           
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            
           log_message('error', "Email Not Send form admin agianst ".$data['email']." \n" .print_r($response));
        
           return false;
        }
        return true;
```

Comment: It looks like `$this->ecomhut->getConfig('noreplyEmail')` is not returning a valid email address to use as the From email. Can you check what it is returning?

Comment: Above mentioned code is right code and $this->ecomhut->getConfig('salesEmail') sending my email.

Comment: The exception says that it isn’t an email, can you double check? What if you replace the function with a string that is an email address just to test?

Comment: Hello Sir, I have updated all my emails and working fine. But still I got same issue
Exception: "$email" must be an instance of SendGrid\Mail\From or a valid email address 
public_html/vendor/sendgrid/sendgrid/lib/helper/Assert.php 61

Comment: That code in Assert is testing the email address that you pass is valid, you can [see that code here](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/blob/5ddb5bf749f9731d5d43fe099f0371c77719d46f/lib/helper/Assert.php#L46-L63). So it looks as though you are not passing a valid (according to PHP) email address. Can you try a different one?

Comment: Thank you Mate, Mistakenly through admin there were space after email. So its just fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

The [SendGrid PHP library](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php) validates that email addresses are being set as the From and To addresses. In this case, the complaint was that the From email address wasn't a valid email address.

```php
$email->setFrom($this->ecomhut->getConfig('salesEmail'));
```

When storing email addresses, in config or in a database, you need to ensure that the string is a valid email address, including removing leading or trailing white space. To help with this, you might consider using the `trim` function to remove that white space

```php
$email->setFrom(trim($this->ecomhut->getConfig('salesEmail')));
```

This could stop future mistakes from affecting the emails getting sent.